# Integrability of a given Laurent polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, uniform-convergence

Does the following hold for all exponents $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|<1$ ?

The following integral on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|y|^{\alpha}}dy < \infty,$$
with $|\cdot|$ denoting the modulus of the evaluated vector.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $|y|$ here? As $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, I assume it is a norm, but there is more than one norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley If the norm isn't specified it is always a safe bet to assume the Euclidean ($L^2$) norm.

Answer (score 0):

This does not hold at all. Consider $n=1$ and $\alpha=1/2$ -
$$\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|y|}}\mathrm dy \\ \text{diverges}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know if there exist some $\alpha$ such that the integral converges ?

Comment: I think the singularity at zero is always a problem.